# Focus control for Custom User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, focus

I have a UserControl defined such that:

```
UserControl
  TextBox
  Button (Clear)
```

I have a `GotFocus` handler on the `UserControl` so that whenever it gets focus, it calls `TextBox.Focus()`. The problem I am running into is that If I click the clear button, it clears the text and then refocuses to the textbox, triggering two GotFocus events on my control. I want this to act as either:

- One GotFocus event
- One GotFocus event (button), One LostFocus event(button), One GotFocus event (textbox)

I have played with `FocusManager.IsFocusScope` to no avail. Is there even a way to trigger a manual `LostFocus` right before I call `Textbox.Focus`?

Comment: Try setting IsFocusable on the UserControl as false?

Comment: Currently, I seem to have fixed this by marking the button as `Focusable=False`....Im not sure that I consider this a good solution as all it does is make it so that the clear button click does not act like a focus change at all

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. `Focusable = false`. Sorry didn't test it.

Answer (score 1):

In your GotFocus event you can check whether the mouse is over the clear button and whether the left mouse button is pressed, in such a case you can ignore the call to `TextBox.Focus():`

```
private void UserControl_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     if ((this.clearButton.IsMouseOver && Mouse.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) == false)
     {
         this.textBox.Focus();
     }
}
```